# Rails 3.1 asset:precompile task failing with "bad URI" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Here is the whole error from `rake assets:precompile --trace`

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
bad URI(is not URI?): 

Tasks: TOP => environment
```

Not much to go on.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the RAILS_ENV variable before running the command? i.e. `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile`

Comment: I did try with with RAILS_ENV=production as well as without (I assumed development would be the default but I'll try that after work).

Comment: So looks like RAILS_ENV=development is working just not production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out to be largely user error and my lack of understanding of how the /environment files are called.  I had a section to parse the CLOUDANT_URL environment variable from Heroku which of course is not available during precompile phase.  This probably should have been more obvious to me.

I moved this out into a separate initializer which has an `if Rails.env.production?` block wrapping it.  I hope that is a reasonable way to handle this.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This message is most likely because you have an illegal character in one of your asset paths or names. By illegal, I mean a character that needs to be encoded to be used in a URL.

I would have thought Rails would do this, but I cannot say for sure without digging into the code.

Have a look for things like spaces and extended characters in filenames, and see if removing these solves the problem.

You can the method `URI.encode(string)` to encode these if that is the case.

Comment: None of the files have anything nonstandard in the naming.  Is there no way to get a more specific error?